# how to remove this outline/border of svg which it is getting from parent element

Tags: html, css

[SVG is getting the green background also which I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idqK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
svg{
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

**If you getting the same issue let us provide the page URL in the comment box so we can review it. Thanks**